# How do you interrupt a Semaphore from a JUnit thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, semaphore

I have an implementation of a method that I want to test.

```
    @Override
public void onMessage(final Message message) {
    try {
        LOG.fine("waiting on semaphore for " + message);
        semaphore.acquire();
        LOG.fine("semaphore acquired for " + message);
        listener.onMessage(message);
        LOG.fine(message + " processed");
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to rigger the InterruptedException from a JUnit test.  In theory I can add hooks to terminate it, but that would pollute the code base with code only used for testing which I would like to avoid.

Comment: could you please explain, you want to call semaphore.release() from junit test when your method is waiting at semaphore.acquire(); ?

Comment: it was just a snippet of a code to test JMS messaging to ensure all messages were sent and processed when I expect it to.  The full source is here : https://github.com/trajano/maven-jee6/blob/master/maven-jee6-test/src/main/java/net/trajano/maven_jee6/test/LatchedMessageListener.java

Comment: I can test that it works, but I can't test the condition where semaphore would cause an interrupted exception.

Comment: What dbf is saying is that you should not release the semaphore if acquire failed.  The finally block should be in a try block that starts after the call to semaphore.acquire().

Answer (score 1):

you should mock the semaphore. your faked semaphore should throw the InterruptedException

Comment: unfortunately the semaphore is created within the class, there's no need to expose the fact that it uses a semaphore.  So if I did what you had suggested then I am adding something extra to the API just for testing.

Comment: 1) you want trigger semaphore (internal object). that means you are already testing internal/implementation specific behaviour. 2) you don't have to change api - there are plenty of technics of changing private variables. 3) there is nothing wrong with changing api for testing. api always should be designed with thinking about testing. just add package scope setSemapthore or extract method that do semaphore.acquire and do partial mocking. u need to fix your design a bit to make your code testable

Answer (score 0):

In my testing interrupting the current thread before calling onMessage, will cause the acquire method to throw even if it didn't need to block, but I don't know if that will happen in all jres.

The other option is to use multiple threads for this.
Have thread one call onMessage, and in it's listener signal thread two to call onMessage and then block until thread 2 is complete.
Have thread two block until thread one has a lock on the semaphore.  Then it should interrupt itself and call onMessage.  Once it gets the expected runtime exception, it should signal thread one to stop blocking.

I'd use two CountDownLatches to have the two threads communicate.

Make sure you terminate both threads if the test fails.